# CSV data from interface to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, csv, interface, import

I have this data from a real time interface call of an url:

```
"DATETIME";"ACTION";"ACTIONTEXT";"POSITION";"AREA";"DRIVERKEY";"DRIVERNAME";"CAR";"LAT";"LON"; 
"21.05.2013 10:59:00";"G";"Arbeitsende";"";"20037100 ARCUS Cottbus";"0000161395E7";"Süsse, Daniel";"Neubuchung";"0";"0"; 
"21.05.2013 19:07:00";"G";"Arbeitsende";"";"20037100 ARCUS Cottbus";"0000161395E7";"Süsse, Daniel";"Neubuchung";"0";"0"; 
"27.05.2013 05:38:05";"K";"Arbeitsbeginn";"D-02625 Bautzen Hanns-Eisler-Straße 10";"";"0000161395E7";"Süsse, Daniel";"BZ-DK 101";"51.17421";"14.45179"; 
"27.05.2013 06:04:25";"K";"Arbeitsbeginn";"D-02733 Cunewalde Gewerbegebiet Roßkaupe 11";"";"00001613B355";"Wypior, Andreas";"BZ-DK 11";"51.09184";"14.53524"; 
"27.05.2013 06:20:26";"K";"Arbeitsbeginn";"D-02733 Cunewalde Gewerbegebiet Roßkaupe 11";"";"000016127326";"Henze, Jens";"BZ-DK 55";"51.09194";"14.53433"; 
"27.05.2013 06:52:33";"K";"Arbeitsbeginn";"D-97792 Riedenberg";"";"000016139436";"Rother, Thomas";"BZ-DK 260";"50.3171";"9.845136";
```

I have tried different functions to get this data directly from the url call imported (structured) to a MySQL database via PHP but I always end up having the entire data in one field, not separated like the following:

```
DATETIME: 21.05.2013 10:59:00 
ACTION: G
ACTIONTEXT: Arbeitsende
...etc
```

Hope you can help/teach me solving this.

The PHP part for saving the csv data (text in body-element) in a temporary csv:

```
$fp = fopen('$url', 'w');

$delimiter = ';';
$headers = array('DATETIME', 'ACTION', 'ACTIONTEXT', 'POSITION');
fputcsv($fp, $headers, $delimiter);

foreach ($worker as $worker) {
    $fields = array($worker->...);
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, $delimiter);
}

fclose($fp);
```

I really do not know how to grab this text (csv-formated) directly from the site to have it correctly imported to a MySQL db.

Comment: You can use the PHP `explode` function to convert a delimited string into an array of strings: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: Show what code you have created thus far to solve the problem

Comment: added a snippet...sorry for my bad english!

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> foreach ($worker as $worker)
> ```

This is looking ugly and "shadows" the $worker array from the global scope with a local variable of the same name in the scope of the loop. In the loop (and worse as that: even after the loop), the original $worker array has been replaced by one of its elements.

Its probably just a typo, but if it is from real code, please consider choosing unique variable names.